# Video card recommendations to drive 6-8 WXGA projectors

Tags: projector, video-adapters, display-port

I'm developing an interactive 3D app in Unity that will be projected on a large curved wall and was curious what video card would best be suited to drive 6-8 projectors (most likely 6). I'm currently thinking of using Sony VPLFW60 projectors and my computer would be a Shuttle SZ170R8 System (i7 6700K, 32GB RAM). Would this be a performant configuration? Any insight or recommendations would be great. I'm currently looking at AMD FirePro W600 and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080. Would these options be appropriate?

The interactive app with be a 3D app, and it will be skinning meshes on the fly which will involve shaders. I looked into Unity's use of the GPU and it says that Unity will use the NVIDIA GPU for PhysX as well as for Shaders.

Comment: Awesome. Then you'll definitely want to go with NVIDIA instead of AMD.

Comment: do you know what nvidia card would support 6 displays/projectors?

Comment: I suspect it's more complicated than you think, especially if you want it to be seamless. Check out the [Nvidia Mosiac Display Configurator](http://www.nvidia.com/content/quadrohmcmosaic/quadrohmcmosaic.asp), but I don't think it's going to give the kind of answer you're looking for. They don't have any single-card recommendations for that many displays.

Comment: In all likelyhood you will need 2 GPU to power that many displays, just for the physical number of connectors.  Your 6 projectors total roughly 80% of a single 4k.  NVIDIA.com says DP 1.43, HDMI 2.0b, DL-DVI so you can connect 3 monitors/displays easily.  Maybe a display port mst expander will work, maybe not.  I think 2 970 or 980 is your best option.